# Can't run minecraft on ubuntu 12.04 lts

Tags: minecraft

I was trying to run minecraft on my laptop with ubuntu 12.04 lts 64 bit. I have a lenovo ideapad p580 with 7.7 Gb and an Intel® Core™ i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz × 4 processor. Under the graphics section of the system overview in ubuntu it says I have none installed. My computer comes with and nvidia geforce graphics card but it isnt recognized. When I start minecraft I get this crash report.

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Shall we play a game?

Time: 24/06/13 7:23 PM
Description: Failed to start game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not init GLX
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.initDefaultPeerInfo(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.<init>(LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.createPeerInfo(LinuxDisplay.java:684)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:854)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:784)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:765)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.a(SourceFile:235)
    at avv.a(SourceFile:56)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(SourceFile:507)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

### A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:

```
-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.5.2
    Operating System: Linux (amd64) version 3.5.0-34-generic
    Java Version: 1.6.0_27, Sun Microsystems Inc.
    Java VM Version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Sun Microsystems Inc.
    Memory: 406175448 bytes (387 MB) / 514523136 bytes (490 MB) up to 1908932608 bytes (1820 MB)
    JVM Flags: 2 total; -Xmx2048M -Xms512M
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Suspicious classes: No suspicious classes found.
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    LWJGL: 2.4.2
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Texture Pack: Default
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
```

I can run it on different versions of linux such as fedora.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your driver could be installed but not in use, have a look in your config file using:

`sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

If your data is not there you may need to add this or similar to this to enable it.

```
Section "Screen"
Identifier "Default Screen"
DefaultDepth 24
EndSection

Section "Module"
Load "glx"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier "Default Device"
Driver "nvidia"
Option "NoLogo" "True"
EndSection
```

And then save and in the terminal type:

`sudo reboot`